# Unity - Get point on edge of the screen that object directed to?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, screen

So this is my problem:

I have an object within the screen that points to a specific direction. For demonstration purposes, I've added a `LineRenderer` to show this direction.

[image]

My final goal is to find the distance between object and the world point where this purple ray intersects with the border of the screen (white outline).

```
float DistToScreenEdge = Vector2.Distance(Object.transform.position, PointOnScreenEdge);
```

But for that I need to get this point, and I have no clue how to do that.

```
Vector2 PointOnScreenEdge = ???
```

[image: PNG-example]

So, the Question:
**How can I get that "PointOnScreenEdge"?**

Note that I always know the direction which object facing and its world coordinates.

*On the Internet, I read that to find a world point relative to the screen, you can use `Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint()` and `Camera.ViewportToWorldPoint()` but I could not figure out how to use them correctly in this situation.*

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [`GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes.html) which returns an array of the six planes making up the Camera frustrum.

> Ordering: [0] = Left, [1] = Right, [2] = Down, [3] = Up, [4] = Near, [5] = Far

You are interested in the ones `0` to `3` and could then do a [`Plane.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane.Raycast.html) against them like

```
[SerializeField] private Camera mainCamera;

private readonly Plane[] planes = new Plane [6];

void Update()
{
    // Wherever you get these to from
    Vector3 origin;
    Vector3 direction;

    var ray = new Ray(origin, direction);

    var currentMinDistance = float.Max;
    var hitPoint = Vector3.zero;
    GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes(mainCamera, planes);
    for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        // Raycast against the plane
        if(planes[i].Raycast(ray, out var distance))
        {
            // Since a plane is mathematical infinite
            // what you would want is the one that hits with the shortest ray distance
            if(distance < currentMinDistance)
            {
                hitPoint = ray.GetPoint(distance);
                currentMinDistance = distance;
            } 
        }
    }  

    // Now the hitPoint should contain the point where your ray hits the screen frustrum/"border"
    lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, hitPoint);
}
```

Depends a bit on if your camera is actually moving/rotating/scaling you might want to get the frustrum planes only **once** at the beginning.

You should also cache the `Camera.main` reference **once** at the beginning.